# Download an image from an html input

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, download

I've a problem with my website. I want when an user add an image from 
this input :

`input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="Image" name="Image">`

I want to automatically download this image. I would prefer to download from front end. I try in JavaScript but not working.... Does anyone have an idea please ?
I despair.
Anatole 
Edit : I want to download the image in my website folder ^^

Answer (score 0):

you can add onchange listener that track input change

user input

```
<input oninput="onclickhandler(this)"></input>
```

script

```
    <script>
           function download(filename, url) {
            var element = document.createElement('a');
            element.setAttribute('href', url);
            element.setAttribute('download', filename);
            document.body.appendChild(element);
            element.click();
             //remove the hidden link 
            //document.body.removeChild(element);
            }

           function onclickhandler(e) {
                var name =  e.files[0].name;
                var file =  e.files[0];
                var blob = new Blob([file]);
                var url  = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                download(name,url);
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, i think my question was not correct, i want to download the image in the website folder. To be able to use them after. Thanks by advance, Anatole